# Prevent other composables in a box to be focusable and clickable, Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

When placing 2 or more composables in a Box() in jetpack compose, even if they overlap, they can be focused and clicked through each other, is there a way to prevent this behavior?

```kotlin
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "Should NOT be clickable and focusable")
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                brush = SolidColor(Color.Gray),
                alpha = 0.8f
            ),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = "Should be clickable and focusable")
        }
    }
```

resulting in:
[image]

Expected behavior is when the button on the top is visible, I don't want the button in the top to be clickable And focusable.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Added code and an image with more information @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: Button(enabled = false, onClick = {}) { Text("Should be clickable and focusable") } }

Comment: Thanks @MichalMikyJankovský , this approach works but what if I want to disable all the buttons and focusables on a composable, for example there are multiple composables that include multiple button each, and I want to disable all of them at once, in this situation it'd be very messy to do this on each button.

Comment: I think disabled buttons are (in the most of use-cases) "anti-pattern" in general...